# Anyone know a way to get AT&T's wireless proxy to not timeout after 45 seconds?

Tags: android, ios, network-programming, cellular-network

We have verified that long requests timeout on AT&T's cellular network (either 3G or LTE) after 45 seconds. This does not happen on Verizon or Sprint. Doesn't matter iOS or Android phones or how you connect. Connecting to the same web servers over WIFI or wired networks has no issues. What you see on a long request is a 504 error from AT&T's proxy. Does anyone know if there is a request header that can tell the AT&T proxy to give us more time? Or someone to ask at AT&T? Sure we can implement complicated polling solutions but the issue - the system that is being called can takes 2 mins to return anything - is not under our control.

Don't expect any solutions here but you never know :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue with 504 Gateway timeout as well as other problems related to slow connections.

I have an application that sends images and data to a web server.  These images were high res 2-3MB images.  I was constantly having to check for gateway timeouts, broken PIPE errors, ECONNRESET timeouts.   After looking into the proxy for AT&T I found a workaround, on the Nexus 4 at least,  which involved removing the proxy altogether.

On the Nexus 4 the setting is located under Settings>mobile network settings> Access Point Names> Access Point(mine was ATT WAP)> Proxy.  I removed wireless.cingular.com and left it blank.

Note that there is also a proxy for MMS.  I assume that this one should be left alone in order to receive MMS's.  I've heard of some phone's where the two are not decoupled.  In such cases you'd probably have to make another Access Point copying all of the info from the original, including the proxy, and then swapping between the two modes.

Comment: Not a solution for a mass market iOS app though :-) We had to build a different service to avoid the long calls.